# How to request or remove the focus on edittext using data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am learning `mvvm` structure and making an app using `mvvm` structure and `data binding` also.

Now, what I want to do is, I wanted to fetch a user from sharedpreference, If I am getting a user successfully then, I would set the name of usr to `edittext1`. In that case, *I want to request focus on edittext2*.

> How to achieve that using databinding? (in such a way that i don't
>   have to use activity. The job should be done using view model and xml
>   only.)

I have tried that using following way.

**StartGameViewModel**

```
public class StartGameViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static String TAG="StartGameViewModel";

    private Preference<User> preference;
    public ObservableField<String> player1Name=new ObservableField<>("");
    public ObservableField<String> player2Name=new ObservableField<>("");

    public ObservableBoolean shouldRequestFocus=new ObservableBoolean(false);


    StartGameViewModel(Preference preference){
        this.preference=preference;
    }

    public void getPreference() {
        preference.get(Constants.CURRENT_USER,User.class)
                .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(User user) {
                        player1Name.set(user.name);
                        shouldRequestFocus.set(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       Log.i(TAG,"user is logged out");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.i(TAG,"Completed Preference");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**activity_start_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.StartGameActivity">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="startGameViewModel"
            type="com.sevenbits.android.mvvmsample.viewmodel.StartGameViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_bg">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Players Name"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/input_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_player1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Player1"
                    android:text="@{startGameViewModel.player1Name}"
                    app:addTextChangedListener="@{startGameViewModel.Player1Watcher}" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_player2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Player2"
                    android:text="@{startGameViewModel.player2Name}"
                    app:addTextChangedListener="@{startGameViewModel.Player2Watcher}" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
            android:paddingStart="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_layout" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**StartGameActivity:**

```
public class StartGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityStartGameBinding activityStartGameBinding;
    StartGameViewModel startGameViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initDataBinding();
        setStartGameListener();
    }

    private void initDataBinding() {
        activityStartGameBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_start_game);

        StartGameViewModelFactory startGameViewModelFactory= Injection.provideStartGameViewModelFactory(this);
        startGameViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,startGameViewModelFactory).get(StartGameViewModel.class);
        activityStartGameBinding.setStartGameViewModel(startGameViewModel);

        startGameViewModel.getPreference();
        if(startGameViewModel.shouldRequestFocus.get())
            findViewById(R.id.et_player2).requestFocus();
    }

    private void setStartGameListener() {
        findViewById(R.id.start_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent=new Intent(StartGameActivity.this,GameActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.PLAYER1_NAME,startGameViewModel.player1Name.get());
            intent.putExtra(Constants.PLAYER2_NAME,startGameViewModel.player2Name.get());
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: @Wizard I wanted to to know weather is there any way to do it using databinding?

Comment: AFAIK, `Databinding` is meant to bind the data. You can not do all the things using `Databinding`.

Comment: Ok . @Wizard Thanks for reply. I thought that we can request a focus using xml, so we can also achieve this thing too.

Comment: Cool. But, you should consider what other says!

Comment: Ok @Wizard. Thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 8):

Very simple via binding adapter

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("requestFocus")
fun requestFocus(view: TextView, requestFocus: Boolean) {
    if (requestFocus) {
        view.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        view.requestFocus()
    }
}



             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_company"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="32"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"

                app:requestFocus="@{company.requestFocus}" />
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to request focus again after having focused it once, the view ill ignore the second time you sent it true if it was focused before

Comment: @A.Steenbergen you may set false before true .. then it's gonna work

Comment: `Could not resolve requestFocus as an accessor or listener on the attribute`. any idea why??? @A.Steenbergen

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I was not able to solve the issue with the current answer. Posting my answer here:

in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation15"
    app:requestFocus="@{viewmodel.focus}"/>
```

And in the viewModel, I had a Boolean variable declared as

```
val focus = true
```

And the binding adapter is as follows:

```
companion object{
    @BindingAdapter("requestFocus")
    @JvmStatic fun requestFocus(editText: EditText, requestFocus: Boolean){
        if(requestFocus){
            editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
            editText.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening here is, Since `app:requestFocus` is written inside the xml, it will invoke the binding adapter with the `focus` Boolean, which is given as the value for the attribute for `app:requestFocus`.

In my case, I didn't want to remove focus, that's why I used Boolean. If it needs to be changed, using a `livedata` and set the value, and update the binding adapter accordingly

**Disclaimer**: I am new to MVVM and Databinding, someone please correct me if I am wrong.